# Forcing dates vector into string in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with some dates.

```
Date
1980-09-15
1981-07-08
2013-06-05
```

I want to create this

```
c("1980-09-15","1981-07-08","2013-06-05")
```

I tried to paste `dates_2 <- c(paste(dates))` with no success since it assigns some character vectors to each one.

Comment: Have you tried `as.vector(df$Date)`? where `df` is your `data.frame`.

Comment: Yes, that did not work for me. That is, it still converts the Dates to characters.

Comment: what about `as.character(df$Date)` for characters or just `dates <- df$Date` for dates

Comment: Those don't exactly obtain what I am looking for. I want to have the dates where I can physically create c("1980-09-15","1981-07-08","2013-06-05") .. to add this to a function.

Comment: `dput(as.character(df$date))`?

Comment: Solved! Thanks, Frank. And thanks to Saurabh and AndS for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frank solved this a while back with

```
dput(as.character(df$date))
```